# Find X-Intercept of $\cos(xa)b$

Tags: trigonometry

I need the X-intercepts of a cosine function, but I have two variables changing the x-intercept, but I can't find the pattern. The equation is $\cos(xa)b$.
How can I find the X-intercepts? (I also do need a solution that could be written as a function in a program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos (ax)(b)=0$
$\cos (ax)=0$

$\cos x=0$ when $x= \frac \pi2 + n\pi$
$\cos ax=0$ when $x= \frac {(2n+1)\pi}{2a}$

Comment: found it as $3pi/2a$